# reference variable and pointer problem

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, reference

I have a pointer which is pointing to an integer variable. Then I assign this pointer to a reference variable. Now when I change my pointer to point some other integer variable, the value of the reference variable doesn't change. Can anyone explain why?

```
int rats = 101;
int * pt = &rats;
int & rodents = *pt;                                // outputs    
cout << "rats = " << rats;                          // 101
cout << ", *pt = " << *pt;                          // 101
cout << ", rodents = " << rodents << endl;          // 101
cout << "rats address = " << &rats;                 // 0027f940
cout << ", rodents address = " << &rodents << endl; // 0027f940
int bunnies = 50;
pt = &bunnies;

cout << "bunnies = " << bunnies;                    // 50
cout << ", rats = " << rats;                        // 101  
cout << ", *pt = " << *pt;                          // 50
cout << ", rodents = " << rodents << endl;          // 101
cout << "bunnies address = " << &bunnies;           // 0027f91c
cout << ", rodents address = " << &rodents << endl; // 0027f940
```

We assigned pt to bunnies, but the value of rodents is still 101. Please explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
int & rodents = *pt;
```

is creating a reference to what `pt` is pointing to (i.e. `rats`). It's not a reference to the pointer `pt`.

Later, when you assign `pt` to point to `bunnies`, you would not expect the `rodents` reference to change.

EDIT: To illustrate @Als point, consider the following code:

```
int value1 = 10;
int value2 = 20;
int& reference = value1;
cout << reference << endl; // Prints 10
reference = value2; // Doesn't do what you might think
cout << reference << endl; // Prints 20
cout << value1 << endl; // Also prints 20
```

The second `reference` assignment does **not** change the reference ltself. Instead, it applies the assignment operator (`=`) to the thing referred to, which is `value1`.

`reference` will always refer to `value1` and cannot be changed.

It's a little tricky to get your head around at first, so I recommend you take a look at Scott Meyer's excellent books [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876) and [More Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163371X). He explains all this much better than I can.

Comment: so you mean to say that if rodents is assigned to one variable, then it cannot reference to any other variable again.

Comment: @Naphstor: Yes you are correct.References cannot be bound to reference any other variable, they always remain references to the variable to which they were bound to.